# Sampling without replacement while avoiding an element

Tags: sampling, importance-sampling

Let $p$ be a distribution over $N$ objects, pick an object $k$ from $N$, and define $p^*(x)$ to be 0 if $x = k$ and $p(x) / (1 - p(k))$ otherwise.

Suppose I want to sample $n$ items from $p^*$ without replacement (that is, every time I draw an element, I set it aside and renormalise the probabilities of the remaining items), but I can only draw samples WOR from $p$. Is the following a valid sampling WOR scheme for $p^*$:

1. Draw $n+1$ items from $p$ WOR.
2. If any of the $n+1$ items are equal to $k$, remove it from the sample.
3. Otherwise take the first $n$ items.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be. My intuition is as follows.

Consider drawing $N$ items from $p$ WOR. This is a random ordering of your items. Picking the $n$ first items from this list is equivalent to drawing $n$ items from $p$.

Now consider the effect of your steps 2 and 3 of this interpretation. 2 and 3 together is equivalent to removing items $k$ from your list of $N$ randomly ordered items and picking the remaining $n$ first items is equivalent to drawing $n$ items from the set of size $N-N_k$ where $N_k$ items $k$ have been removed in accordance with $p^*$.